# How to use an array of string in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I need to make an array of string where I can store either 3 or 5 words like {"banana, peach, pear"}, or {"orange", "pear", "silantro", "ginger", "mandarine"}.

I'm confused if I should make an array of string pointer(to dynamically allocate the memory depending on the size of the array-3 or 5), or just have an array of string with the statically allocated memory of 5. And how to initialize it/set it to null/use it in the constructors.

I'm not allowed to use vector.
When I declared an array of size 5, the problem started in the default constructor.
I don't know how to set it to null...
// string multiple_fruits[5]
// multiple_fruits[] = { nullptr, };

So I'm using an array of string pointer here, is there a better way?
What am I doing wrong?? HAAAALP

```
//.h file
class Fruit {
  char* single_fruit;
  string* multiple_fruits;
  int num_Fruits;
};
 

//.cpp file
Fruit::Fruit() {
  single_fruit = nullptr;
  multiple_fruits = nullptr;
  num_Fruits = 0;
}
 
Fruit::Fruit(const char* singlefruit, string* multiplefruits, int numFruits) {
  single_fruit = new char[strlen(singlefruit) + 1];
  strcpy_s(single_fruit, strlen(singlefruit) + 1, singlefruit);
 
  multiple_fruits = new string[numFruits];

  for (int i = 0; i < numFruits; i++) {
    multiple_fruits[i] = multiplefruits[i];
  }
  num_fruits = numFruits;
}
 
int main() {
  Fruit A;
  A("apple", {"banana", "peach", "pear"}, 3)
  Fruit B;
  B("lemon", {"orange", "pear", "silantro", "ginger", "mandarine"}, 5);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh I was just trying to make it bold, but now I removed the **. an array of char can only store 1 word but I need to make an array to store multiple words. How do I do this?

Comment: Why are you declaring an array of `string` pointers? `string* multiple_fruits[5];`

Comment: Are you allowed to use `string` or not? If yes, then use it for `single_truit`.

Comment: Is there a reason to use c strings? C++ supports [strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) and [arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/)

Comment: @TedLyngmo cause honestly I'm only familiar with char and I didn't know what to create lol...is there a better way???

Comment: If you want an array of `std::string` just `std::string multiple_fruits[5];`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm allowed to use string but I never used it so I don't know if there is any syntax error. I'd love to use String for both veriables but the problem is that the char works here but the string doesn't work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh thanks but it still doesn't seem to work...there's gotta be somethng wrong in the way I set it to null and etc?

Comment: You class definition does not end with `;` and you haven't declared the `Fruit` constructor that you later define.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I wanted to make an array of string to be able to store maximum 5 words...so I can store 3 words or 5 words....  multiple_fruits[] = { nullptr, }; <= this part creates an error already! :S

Comment: @TedLyngmo
Oh thanks I edited it! But I still don't know how to set an array of string to null...gahhhh why is this so difficult :S

Comment: multiple_fruits[] = "";  multiple_fruits[] = { "", }; multiple_fruits[5] = 0; I'm trying EVERY way but still have no idea. :'(

Comment: You cannot. multiple_fruits was declared as an array of five elements so it will *always* be five elements. You could add a field to specify how many slots of multiple_fruits are filled, but that is an accident waiting to happen. Perhaps your assignment requires to use dynamic memory management so you can vary the size of multiple_fruits? In that case, re-read your textbook's section on `new[]` and `delete[]`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I changed it! (string* multiple_fruits;) and I set it to nullptr in the defulat constructor. (multiple_fruits = nullptr;) and dynamically allocated memory in the custom constructor and used the for loop to store each words....am I doing it right?

Comment: There's no need to use pointers at all. Try to stay away from pointers as long as you can.

Comment: Could you please describe the problem you're trying to solve? You fundamentally changed the code. At the beginning it was a fixed sized array. Now the size is dynamic. Are you allowed to use vectors?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I need to make an array of string where I can store either 3 words or 5 words.....Since I need to declare 2 objects (one with 3 words and another with 5 words). I'm confused if I should make an array of string pointer(to dynamically allocate the momery depending on the size of the array-3 or 5), or just have an array of string with statically allocated memory of 5. And how to initialize it/set it to null/use it in the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using a proper declaration of the array argument to the constructor.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::copy
#include <iterator>  // std::begin, std::end
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
class Fruit {
public:
    Fruit();
    Fruit(const std::string& singlefruit, const std::string (&multiplefruits)[N]);
    
    size_t size() const;

private:
    std::string single_fruit;
    std::string multiple_fruits[N];
};

template<size_t N>
Fruit<N>::Fruit() {}

template<size_t N>
Fruit<N>::Fruit(const std::string& singlefruit, const std::string (&multiplefruits)[N]) 
    : // colon indicates the start of the member initializer list
    single_fruit(singlefruit)
{
    std::copy(std::begin(multiplefruits), std::end(multiplefruits), multiple_fruits);
}

template<size_t N>
size_t Fruit<N>::size() const { return N; }

int main() {
    Fruit A("apple", {"banana", "peach", "pear"});
    std::cout << A.size() << '\n';

    Fruit B("lemon", {"orange", "pear", "silantro", "ginger", "mandarine"});
    std::cout << B.size() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
3
5
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) for this:

```
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

class Fruit {
public:
  Fruit(const std::string &singlefruit, const std::initializer_list<std::string> &multiplefruits) : single_fruit{singlefruit}, multiple_fruits{new std::string[multiplefruits.size()]}, num_Fruits{multiplefruits.size()} {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < num_Fruits; ++i) {
      multiple_fruits[i] = *(multiplefruits.begin() + i);
    }
  }
  ~Fruit() {
    delete[] multiple_fruits;
  }
private:
  std::string single_fruit;
  std::string *multiple_fruits;
  std::size_t num_Fruits;
};

int main() {
  Fruit A("apple", {"banana", "peach", "pear"});
  Fruit B("lemon", {"orange", "pear", "silantro", "ginger", "mandarine"});
}
```

I allocated memory for the elements and deleted the memory in the destructor.

You can't declare a variable in one line and call the constructor in the next line.

Comment: Thank you Thomas! I will digest this :0